# Is there a proper documentation of AWS Amplify React Components?

Tags: reactjs, aws-amplify

I wanted to work with **Picker or TextPicker** component of **AWS Amplify** mentioned [here](https://aws-amplify.github.io/docs/js/storage#picker) which clearly doesnt tell us about all the props and how to interact with that component.

I head over to their https://aws-amplify.github.io/amplify-js/api/ (API documentation). I cant find any mention of Picker or TextPicker.

Is there any other location for docs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a docs page for the Photo picker in the docs you linked to, it's here https://aws-amplify.github.io/amplify-js/api/classes/photopickerclass.html

Alternatively, you could just look at the source for the component in question, which you can find here https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-js/tree/4644b4322ee260165dd756ca9faeb235445000e3/packages/aws-amplify-react/src/Widget.

I agree the docs here are lacking. There seems to be a edit/feedback button above each component on [the first link you posted(https://aws-amplify.github.io/docs/js/storage#picker). perhaps you could leave this feedback so that the docs are better fort everyone. Even better, if you have a specific question about the component, open a new stack question, we can try and figure it out, and then we can edit the docs to better address the problem for the next person.

Comment: @dnafication can you please mark the answer accepted if it helped.